# heroku nil class error if block rollbar

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

first step after run `heroku cli`, `heroku` connect to `api.rollbar.com` ..

[image]

but my ISP block connection with `api.rollbar.com:443`,and delete this connection:

[image]

then heroku can't continue and print `error` and exit:
[image]

how to i can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occurring because Rollbar's servers are hosted by SoftLayer (owned by IBM), and IBM is not doing business with Iranian companies nor allowing internet traffic from Iran yet despite the lifting of sanctions.

More details on this IBM policy are described in http://www.thewhir.com/web-hosting-news/ibm-softlayer-blocks-services-in-iran-as-us-lifts-sanctions .